# How to debug a TypeError "no attribute __getitem__"?

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

I'm having some difficulties with my code in python. I want to create a code which will check if the number of a credit card is valid. But it keep showing me the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\George\Desktop\FRONTISTHRIAKH ASKHSH 6.py", line 14, in <module>
    if int(x[0][0])>4 and int(x[0][0])<7:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here is my code:

```
n=raw_input()
while n!="END" and n!="end":
    s=0
    x=[n]
    if int(x[0][0])>4 and int(x[0][0])<7:
        if x[0][3]==" " or x[0][3]=="-":        
            if x[0][3]==" ":
                x[0].remove(" ")
            else:
                x[0].remove("-")
                if len(x[0])>16:
                    print False
                else:                    
                    a=[int(x[0][0]),int(x[0][1]),int(x[0][2]),int(x[0][3]),int(x[0][4]),int(x[0][5]),int(x[0][6]),int(x[0][7]),int(x[0][8]),int(x[0][9]),int(x[0][10]),int(x[0][11]),int(x[0][12]),int(x[0][13]),int(x[0][14])]
                    for i in range(0,14,2):
                        a[i]=2*a[i]
                        if a[i]/10!=0:
                            a[i]=a[i]/10+a[i]%10
                    for i in range(15):
                        s=s+a[i]
                    if s%10==0:
                        print True
                    else:
                        print False


        else:
            if len(x[0])>16:
                    print False
            else:
                a=[int(x[0][0]),int(x[0][1]),int(x[0][2]),int(x[0][3]),int(x[0][4]),int(x[0][5]),int(x[0][6]),int(x[0][7]),int(x[0][8]),int(x[0][9]),int(x[0][10]),int(x[0][11]),int(x[0][12]),int(x[0][13]),int(x[0][14])]
                for i in range(0,14,2):
                    a[i]=2*a[i]
                    if a[i]/10!=0:
                        a[i]=a[i]/10+a[i]%10
                for i in range(15):
                    s=s+a[i]
                if s%10==0:
                    print True
                else:
                    print False

    else:
        print False
    n=raw_input
```

Comment: 1. Incomplete code 
2. What the input in your example?
3. You should give some context: what's a valid credit card number?

---- Anyway, it seems `n` is a simple array and you try to use it as a 2D array..

Comment: Your code is extremely hard to read. Break it up into meaningful functions and use better variable names.

Comment: What appears if you inject `print(type(x))` between lines 13 and 14?

Answer (score 3):

Your ***second*** call to `raw_input` doesn't call the function:

```
n=raw_input
```

Should be

```
n=raw_input()
```

Comment: thank you for the comment but that's not my major problem right now.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing: Yes it is. That is the reason for the error message you gave. When adding the parenthesis, that error message goes away.

Comment: @MaximeLorant that is where the error *appears*, but Lennart is correct about where is is *caused*. If `n = raw_input`, then `x[0] == raw_input` and `x[0][0] == raw_input[0]`, hence the error. When `n` is a string, `x[0][0]` is its first character.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has various issues. For example, you convert the input string to an array `x`, of which you subsequently only use `x[0]`. That's very confusing. Also you shouldn't call `int` on the characters of the string until you are sure that they are decimal digits. An exception will be raised if you call int on a non-digit. And you shouldn't consider the strings with spaces or dashes and without as two separate cases, because the core algorithm is the same.

I've extracted that core algorithm into a separate function, which you can call on the input string. The input is supposed to be direct user input and may therefore be an invalid credit card number for various reasons. The function returns `None` if the test is passed and an informative string that describes the kind of error otherwise.

The code performs various steps: First "purify" the string so that it only contains digits. If the user formats the string with spaces or dashes, these are strippe regardless of their poistion. (Letters and other non-digits are also stripped, which is unfortunate; catching these weeds out futher user errors.) Next the function checks for the correct length and applies the Luhn algorithm:

```
def invalid_credit_card_number(s):
    """ Returns None if s is a valid credit card number
        and a string describing the error otherwise.
        The string may contains non-digits, which are ignored.
    """

    # strip dashes from string and convert to list of digits    
    dig = [int(x) for x in list(s) if "0" <= x <= "9"]

    if len(dig) != 16:
        return "Invalid length"

    if dig[0] < 5 and dig[0] > 6:
        return "Invalid initial digit"

    # multiply and cast out nines for every other digit   
    for i in range(0, 16, 2):
        dig[i] *= 2
        if dig[i] > 9:
            dig[i] -= 9

    # calculate checksum            
    s = (9 * sum(dig)) % 10

    if s != 0:
        return "Invalid checksum"

    return None
```

Note that the [Wikipedia page on Luhn's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn) has example code in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `raw_input` is a credit card number:

```
n == "1234567891234567"
```

Then `x = [n]` gives you

```
x == ["1234567891234567"]
```

This isn't terribly helpful; did you want `x = list(n)`?

```
x == ['1', '2', '3', ...]
```

This is why you keep having to use `x[0]` to get anything done.

Also, you have a whole chunk of code duplicated within your `if: else:` structure, due to your handling of punctuation. You can turn a string into a list of only digits using:

```
l = [int(c) for c in s if c.isdigit()]
```

which handles both removing any punctuation and making everything an integer, saving your (not terribly elegant) line of

```
a = [int(x[0][0]), int(x[0][1]), ...]
```

Putting it together, I would separate the actual test into a function (which allows you to use it programmatically in other contexts):

```
def ccn_is_valid(s):
    """Validate a supplied string s as a credit card number."""
    LENGTH = 16
    l = [int(c) for c in s if c.isdigit()]
    # Test 1: length
    if len(l) != LENGTH:
        return False
    # Test 2: first digit
    if not 4 <= l[0] <= 7:
        return False
    # Test 3: algorithm
    for i in range(0, LENGTH, 2):
        l[i] *= 2
        if l[i] % 10:
            l[i] = l[i] / (10 + (l[i] % 10))
    return not sum(l) % 10
```

(Note that `range([start, ]stop[, step])` *doesn't include `stop`*)

This function will `return` as soon as any test fails, so doesn't bother continuing to process once it knows the number isn't valid.

Then you can loop through the user requests using:

```
while True:
    s = raw_input("Enter credit card number or 'end': ")
    if s.lower() == "end":
        break
    print(ccn_is_valid(s))
```