# Disgruntled with VAT number check digit algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I'd coded a function for checking the VAT number digit of corporate personhood.  That function works, but it's ugly (too long and too complex).

I'm new programming Python and would like to improve the function so I need some feedback and help.

The VAT number is always 9 digits, the first a char the rest are numerals.

The char must be in the `letras` string.

The last number is the check digit.

With the other seven numerals the algorithm is this:

1. Digits in even order are summed in a subtotal.
2. Digits in odd order are multiplied by 2 (each one), if the result of each is  > 10 then units are added to the tens, and then the four results are subtotalized.
3. The subtotals gotten in steps 1 and 2 are added.
4. Get the units, if is a 0 then the check digit is 0, in other case is
   deducted of 10. The result is the check digit.

An example of valid VAT number is A58818501

**The code**

```
def validarCodigoCIF(entrada):
    """
    :param: entrada: str
    :rtype: bool
    """
    letras = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSVW"
    if len(entrada) != 9 or entrada[0] not in letras:
        return False
    numero = entrada[1:10]
    pares = int(numero[1]) + int(numero[3]) + int(numero[5])
    impares = 0
    for i in range(0, 8, 2):
        j = int(numero[i]) * 2
        if j < 10:
            impares += j
        else:
            impares += j - 9
    digito = str(pares+impares)[-1]
    if int(digito) == 0:
        checkCIF = 0
    else:
        checkCIF = 10 - int(digito)
    # print(checkCIF)
    if str(checkCIF) == entrada[-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

entradaCodigoCIF = input('Enter the VAT number: ')
print(validarCodigoCIF(entradaCodigoCIF))
```

Comment: This is probably better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com since it appears to be working code you wish to make prettier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shortened version

```
def check(vat_num):
    if len(vat_num) != 9 or vat_num[0] not in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSVW":
        return False # trivial checks first
    nums = list(map(int, vat_num[1:8])) # numbers to check
    nums[1::2] = ((i * 2) - (9 if i > 4 else 0) for i in nums[1::2]) # alter odds
    return int(vat_num[8]) == (sum(nums) % 10) # compare to check digit
```

Note the following interesting* features:

1. Use of `[1::2]` to get every other item from an iterable;
2. Use of `map(int, ...)` to convert all items in an interable to integers; and
3. Use of `% 10` (modulo) to easily get just the digits part of a number.

* may not be interesting

Answer (score 0):

The first problem to tackle is that your function is too long:

```
def calculate_pares(numero):
    return int(numero[1]) + int(numero[3]) + int(numero[5])

def calculate_impares(numero):
    result = 0
    for i in range(0, 8, 2):
        j = int(numero[i]) * 2
        if j < 10:
            result += j
        else:
            result += j - 9

    return result

def calculate_check_cif(entrada):
    numero = entrada[1:10]
    pares = calculate_pares(numero)
    impares = calculate_impares(numero)

    digito = str(pares+impares)[-1]
    if int(digito) == 0:
        return 0

    return 10 - int(digito)

def validarCodigoCIF(entrada):
    """
    :param: entrada: str
    :rtype: bool
    """
    letras = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSVW"
    if len(entrada) != 9 or entrada[0] not in letras:
        return False

    checkCIF = calculate_check_cif(entrada)

    # print(checkCIF)
    return str(checkCIF) == entrada[-1]
```

This is just a first step, I think you get the idea. Further improvements are then easier when you have small functions.

Also, it would be easier if you wrote your code in English - probably people would be then able to help you in discovering more meaningful functions than just by blind partitioning/guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the VAT number uses the Luhn checksum I present a modifuied version I have recently posted in [an (unaccepted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920911/how-to-debug-a-typeerror-no-attribute-getitem/20921634#20921634) about credit card numbers.

The function is not necessarily shorter than yours, but uses another approach: It returns `None` on valid numbers and a short error message on failure. It also ensures that the digits after the initial letter are valid and allows spaces and some punctuation.

```
def invalid_cif_code(s):
    """ Returns None if s is a valid CIF code and a string 
        describing the error otherwise. The string may contain 
        spaces and punctuation, which is ignored.
    """

    # strip punctuation from string
    s = [x for x in s if x not in " \t.-"]

    if len(s) != 9:
        return "Invalid length"

    if s[0] not in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSVW":
        return "Invalid initial letter"

    # convert numerical part to list of digits
    try:
        code = [int(x) for x in s[1:]]
    except ValueError:
        return "Invalid non-digit in number"

    # multiply and cast out nines for every other codeit   
    for i in range(0, 8, 2):
        code[i] *= 2
        if code[i] > 9:
            code[i] -= 9

    # calculate checksum            
    s = (9 * sum(code)) % 10

    if s != 0:
        return "Invalid checksum"

    return None
```

[Typical Programmer](http://typicalprogrammer.com/learning-by-example-javacript-luhn/) has a more elegant solution to the Luhn checksum (albeit appied to credit card numbers and written in Javascript) that uses an array for the odd numbers.